# What is the first derivative of non-commutative powers?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, derivatives

Suppose $Y(t)$ is a differentiable (in $t$), non-commutative operator, like a matrix.

Then, what is $\frac{d}{dt} Y(t)^{n}$ ?

For
$n = 0$ we have $0$,

for $n = 1,$ we have $Y'(t),$

for $n=2,$ $Y'(t)Y(t) + Y(t)Y'(t),$

for $n=3,$ $Y'(t)Y(t)^2 + Y(t)Y'(t)Y(t) + Y(t)^2Y'(t).$

As you can see, it doesn't simplify to the same factorial generalization as in the commutative case where $\frac{d}{dt} t^n = nt^{n-1}.$ What is the general pattern in the form of a sum (and maybe a sum of a product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is
$$
(Y^n)' = \sum_{k=1}^n Y^{k-1} \,Y'\,Y^{n-k}.
$$
You can prove it by induction.

Comment: Thank you for that formula, I'll try testing it out to see that it works.

Comment: sorry I was not able to confirm that your formula works. Take $n=4,$ then we have $\frac{d}{dt}Y^4 = Y'Y^3 + YY'Y^2 + Y^2Y'Y + Y^3Y'.$ But the very first term of your formula contradicts this,  $Y^{4-1}Y'Y^{4-1} = Y^3Y'Y^3.$

Comment: No, the first term is $Y^0\,Y'\,Y^{4-1} = Y'\,Y^3$ ... the first exponent is $k-1$, not $n-1$.

Comment: Oh I see, I saw $n - 1$ in the first power, but it should be $k - 1$ in the first power. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Great, looks like it works! Thank you for your quick insights.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\frac{d}{dt} Y(t)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n Y_{k,n}(t)$$ where

$$Y_{k,n}(t) = Y(t) \dots Y^\prime(t) \dots Y(t)$$ with $n$ terms equal to $Y(t)$ except the $k$-th term that is replaced with $Y^\prime(t)$.

Comment: I was hoping for an explicit answer in summation/product notation for the $Y_{k,n}$ term, do you think that's possible?

Comment: The answer of [ll-3-14](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/731946/ll-3-14) goes in that direction.

Comment: Well, it looks so far as though the formula is erroneous, perhaps you could correct it?